# How to suggest a plot type from a csv file data python

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-visualization

How to build a recommender for the data visualization in python.
For example, if a csv file contains multiple columns with different data.
I need to create x axis as column and y axis as data (rows).
Then I need to read each columns and based on the data I need to recommend it as line graph or scatter or pie chart or other plots using mathplotlib or any other visualization tools.

How can I determine which chart to use for data for each column?

Comment: Hi. This may sound stupid, but first I'll think how can you do manually and, after that, think about some machine-learning technique to implement. Once you define this, it will be easier to help you :)

Comment: I am not sure whether this task is within a reach of current technologies. Building a visualization for the purpose of building of a visualization is meaningless. Visualizations are only good if they produce something meaningful to us humans therefore you would need to let humans rank how good the produced visualizations are and train a model based on this feedback. I am not saying that it is impossible but I can't image how one might go about achieving that. Might be an interesting area of research.

Comment: For instance, how do you determine if you want to plot a scatterplot or a regular plot _based on raw data_? These kinds of plots are basically the same: you plot the points and then decide if you want to connect them with a line or not. And... there doesn't seem to be a way of guessing if the user wants the line or not. You _could_ make some assumptions based on how messy the data is (if it looks random, the connecting line will jump around too much), but then you'll need a measure of randomness and a cutoff at which to switch to a scatter plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of plots largely depends on if your data is categorical or continuous.

Assuming that your data is relatively clean, you can call `df.dtypes` to determine the data types of the columns. If they are continuous (`float`), you can use scatter plots, distribution plots, etc, depending on what you want to do.

If they are `object`, you can use `df['col'].value_counts()` to get the most frequent values, select those who are important enough, and create a pie chart, etc.

If they are `int` (integers), you can use a bar chart with `value_counts()`, or pie charts, etc. You get the idea.

```
Out[18]: 
col1    int32
col2    int32
col3    object
col4    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Float and int based assumption may not work always.I think in model creation and find out the algorithm approach and decision, can decide on plot type such as classification plots or categorical plot type.